# Comment traduire « to go for a drink » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

Dans les phrases anglaises suivantes :

> Would you like to go for a drink?
>   Shall we go for a drink?

Comment peut-on exprimer « *to go for a drink* » en français ? J'ai vu des expressions comme :

- prendre un pot
- prendre un verre
- laisse aller boire un verre

Laquelle est la plus typique ?

Comment: Je pense qu'il faudrait spécifier où vous vous trouvez dans ce cas ci. Par exemple, au Québec, je n'ai jamais entendu "prendre un pot", mais l'on dit presque toujours "aller prendre un verre".

Comment: "laisse aller boire un verre" n'est pas français. On dit soit "laisser aller" (qui n'a rien à voir avec prendre un verre), soit "aller boire un verre".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Le plus neutre serait « aller prendre un verre », « aller boire un verre ». « Un pot » est un peu familier (entre jeunes collègues, entre étudiants, avec quelqu'un que tu connais bien). « Laisse » n'a rien à faire là, par contre.

Answer (score 14):

« On va boire un coup ? » est plus familier. « On va prendre un verre ? » est adapté à la plupart des cas.

Answer (score 10):

La réponse dépend essentiellement de la variété de français utilisé, selon la variante locale, sociale et les différentes époques.

*Prendre un pot* est plus familier que *prendre un verre* et son emploi argotique commence à dater, *laisser aller boire un verre*, je ne l'ai jamais entendu. On trouve aussi *boire un coup*, *prendre/boire un café*, *prendre/boire un canon*...

Answer (score 7):

On dit organiser un pot lorsque quelqu'un offre à boire de manière officielle (lors de son départ d'entreprise, lorsqu'une mairie organise un événement).

On utilise souvent « boire un coup » avec des personnes que l'on connaît bien. Si on cherche une formule plus formelle, on peut aussi dire « Que diriez-vous de prendre un verre [au bar] ? » ou encore « Est-ce que vous vous laisseriez tenter par un verre ? ». Si l'on souhaite inviter la personne on peut aussi dire « Je vous offre un verre ? ».